# How to find Nearest point on line from a point cordinate in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, buffer, spatial-database, sql-server-spatial

**I want to find out the nearest point on my road network which is a multiline string from a point with lat lon value.**

*The below code I have tried for finding buffer distance line from a point.*

```
DECLARE @a geometry;
SET @a = geometry::Point(73.0127941495,19.26388944035,4326);
    SELECT top 1 * FROM Routes
    WHERE geom.STIntersects(@a.STBuffer(0.002)) = 1 order by @a.STDistance(geom);
```

**I want a solution for finding Nearest point on line from a point cordinate**

Answer (score 2):

This question is a couple of months old, but in SQL Server 2012, you can try and use the **ShortestLineTo** method.

Example (not tested):

```
DECLARE @a geometry;
SET @a = geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(73.0127941495 19.26388944035)',4326);

SELECT TOP (1) *, geom.ShortestLineTo(@a).STStartPoint() as closest_point_on_line
FROM Routes
WHERE geom.STDistance(@a) IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY geom.STDistance(@a);
```

This should return the closest record from the table **Routes** based on  **geom**, along with the tangent point on **geom** to **@a** as long as they have the same SRID.